# How Do I Fix The Following PHP Code Error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a clients site and after installing the Wordpress template, the following error pops up:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/xx/xxxx/html/xxxx/xxxx/wp-content/themes/xxxx/includes/google-fonts.php on line 1.

After analyzing the code, the checker stated there is an unexpected `$fontArrays` on line 1

Could someone please help me with the code and just let me know what I would need to amend in order for the site to function correctly.

Here is the code on line 1:

```
<?phpglobal $fontArrays; $fontArrays =     array (    0 =>     array (      'kind' => 'webfonts#webfont',      'family' =>
```

Comment: Is that really the exact code?

Comment: add a space at the fourth place of the script! `<?php global`

Comment: if it ends like that, then the next line is important as well. Also, you might want to add a space after `<?php`. also, consider using newlines for readability

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code :

```
<?phpglobal
```

to:

```
<?php global
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help! All the code required was a space between <?php and global!! It worked Thank you....